# Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted, This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying setState my highchart option. Second time on click I am trying to update again. Its not calling render or updating my state.

```
class HeatContainer extends Component {

state = {
    options: {
        axisColors: this.axisColors,
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        chart: {
            height: 428
        },
        colorAxis: {
            minColor: this.axisColors.minColor,
            maxColor: this.axisColors.maxColor,
            labels: {
                style: this.style
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            padding: 2,
            headerFormat: '<div class="padding-0-10 padding-b-10"><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td colspan="2"><h5><strong>{point.name}</strong></h5></td></tr>' +
                '<tr><td style="padding-right: 5px;">{point.type} Count: </td><td>{point.colorValue}</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><td style="padding-right: 5px;">Device Count: </td><td>{point.value}</td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table></div>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        var labelStr = this.point.name + ': ' + this.point.colorValue;
                        var allowedLength = (this.point.shapeArgs && this.point.shapeArgs.width) ? Math.round(this.point.shapeArgs.width / 8) : 0;
                        if (allowedLength && (labelStr.length > allowedLength)) {
                            var valueStr = this.point.colorValue + "";
                            var valueLength = valueStr.length;
                            var truncatedStrLength = (allowedLength - (valueLength + 3));
                            if (truncatedStrLength <= 0) {
                                labelStr = this.point.name.substr(0, 1);
                            } else {
                                labelStr = this.point.name.substr(0, truncatedStrLength) + '.. ' + this.point.colorValue;
                            }
                        }
                        return labelStr;
                    },
                    enabled: true,
                    allowOverlap: true,
                    style: {
                        fontFamily: "'univers', Arial, sans-serif",
                        fontSize: 12,
                        color: "#FFF",
                        stoke: "#FFF"
                    }
                },
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: () => {
                            this.loadHierarchy({ chartType: 'momentaryDisturbance', name: this.name, previousLevel: this.previousLevel })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'treemap',
            layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
            animation: false,
            allowDrillToNode: true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            levelIsConstant: false,
            levels: [{
                level: 1,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                borderWidth: 2
            }],
            data: []
        }],
        title: {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    params: { orgId: 1, range: 1, type: "momentary" }
}

loadHierarchy = (obj) => {
    this.setState({
        params: this.setParams(obj.name),
        options: {
            ...this.state.options,
            series: [
                {
                    ...this.state.options.series[0],
                    data: []
                }
            ]
        }
    }, this.updateChartOptions(this))
}

setParams(name) {
    let params = this.state.params;
    if(!("region" in params)) {
        params["region"] = name;
    } else if (!("substation" in params)) {
        params["substation"] = name;
    }

    return params;
}

updateChartOptions(classObj) {
    Services.getFaultData(classObj.state.params).then(res => {
        const renderObj = ProcessData(res, heatChartOptions.axisColors);
        classObj.setState({
            options: {
                ...classObj.state.options,
                series: [
                    {
                        ...classObj.state.options.series[0],
                        data: [...renderObj.chartData]
                    }
                ],
                colorAxis: {
                    ...classObj.state.options.colorAxis,
                    maxColor: renderObj.color
                }
            }
        })
    })
}

shouldComponentUpdate (prevState, nextState) {
    return (nextState.options.series[0].data && nextState.options.series[0].data.length > 0)
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.updateChartOptions(this)
}

render() {
    return (
        <HighchartsReact
            highcharts={Highcharts}
            options={this.state.options}
        />
    );
}
}

export default HeatContainer;
```

Above code updating highchart option on state every click. I am getting data from service and updating.

When page loaded I am calling same service on componentDidMount() that time setstate updating. But second time on click I am calling same service with some data with same structure I am trying to update my state its not working.

State option has click functionality

Comment: loadHierarchy isn't used. *But second time on click* - on which click? The code doesn't contain click handlers. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Comment: @estus Click handler calling my method and I am able to see service data as well. Only thing setState is not setting my state and shouldcomponentupdate also not calling

Comment: @estus Edited my code, State options has click functionality. Hope now you can help me

Comment: I see. I don't see something that would explain this error right off the bat (btw, it may be better to move error message from title to question body). The case seems to be complex and requires some serious debugging. Because of that I'd suggest to provide a workable demo (Stackblitz, etc), this will increase chances to solve the problem. You could also try to offer a bounty later because Highcharts is special topic, you may need as much attention as you can get.

Comment: Hello @raj m, Could you reproduce this problem in some online code editor? You can use this example to start: https://codesandbox.io/s/1ol03rwl3. It will be much simpler to debug.